# JavaScript Input File Not Storing Contents When I Add More Content to Upload

Tags: javascript

Alright so I'm looking so much to this code that I can't figure it out anymore.

So I have a "Select Files" button that I allow users choose multiple files to upload:

```
<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add" name="file[]" class="form-control custom-file-input btn btn-info" value="">
```

Below is the JavaScript. Everything works except this behavior:

- I click and select 1 file to send. It does everything right and send it to the preview. If I click to add more files, it resets the input value and remove the ones I added before. Just from the input, not from the previews.

  ```
  var imagesPreview = function (input) {

    if (input.files) {

        // remove main principal
        $('.no-image').parent().remove();

        // get total files sent this time
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        // get existent files in carousel
        var totalItens = $('.carousel-inner > .item').length;

        // sum all items
        var itensSum = (filesAmount + totalItens);

        // update total in title
        $('.slider-total-items > span').html('(' + itensSum + ')');

        var reader = new FileReader();

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {

            reader.onload = function (event) {

                $('.carousel-inner > .item').removeClass('active');

                if (input.files[0].type.substr(0, 5) == 'video') {
                    var html = '<div class="item ' + (i == 0 ? 'active' : '') + '"><video width="320" height="210" controls><source src="' + event.target.result + '"></video></div>';
                    return
                }

                if (filesAmount > 1) {
                    var html = '<div class="item text-center posts-images-edit ' + (i == filesAmount ? 'active' : '') + '"><img src="' + event.target.result + '"></div>';
                } else {
                    var html = '<div class="item text-center posts-images-edit ' + (i == 1 ? 'active' : '') + '"><img src="' + event.target.result + '"></div>';
                }

                $(html).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }

            if (itensSum > 1) {
                $('#galleryControls').removeClass('hide');
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
    }
   };

    $(function () {
        $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function () {
            imagesPreview(this);
        });
    });
  ```

How can I keep all the files selected on the input?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is just how file inputs work. Every change represents a new [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).

If you want to incrementally build your own list, you'll need to maintain it outside the `<input>` element

```js
const allFilesSelectedEver = [];

const imagesPreview = (input) => {
  allFilesSelectedEver.push(...input.files);

  // now use `allFilesSelectedEver` instead of `input.files`
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I tried that, it still the same when I hit "Save" button